# Probability Question Clock Radio

Tags: probability

In a batch of 8,000 clock radios 7% are defective. A sample of 7 clock radios is randomly selected without replacement from the 8,000 and tested. The entire batch will be rejected if at least one of those tested is defective. What is the probability that the entire batch will be rejected?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

1. Find how many are total defective and total ok in the batch.
2. If everything selected is ok, that means all items come from the ok batch. What is the probability that all selected is ok?
3. What is the probability that at least one of the selected comes from the wrong batch?

Comment: could the one who downvoted please explain the downvote so i can improve my answers?

Comment: Some people downvote answers on questions that doesn't "deserve" an answer, i.e., is deemed off-topic. But not I, so have an upvote :)